# img src doesn't find image, prints alt

Tags: html, image, src, alt

```
<img src=“…/images/adam_photo.jpg” alt=“don't_print_this_damnit” />
```

Displays “don't_print_this_damnit”

web file located:

```
file:///Users/Adam/Documents/adam_webfolder/adam_webfile.html
```

image located:

```
file:///Users/Adam/Documents/adam_webfolder/images/adam_photo.jpg
```

I don't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: Delete the dots

Comment: I've tried several dot-changing alternatives, none of them have worked.

Comment: The quotes are italic. Make sure you use the straight one or single quotes. "/images/...."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using correct quotation marks! (`“`, `”`)

(Unfortunately), correct quotes in the english language aren't correct in the Hypertext Markup Language or pretty much every other markup or programming language. Use the neutral `"`.

Also, you are using the ellipis character (`…`) instead of three dots (`...`).

You're using an office writer program to write your code, am I right? Programs like Word or OpenOffice are wonderful for writing articles, books, etc., but they aren't designed for coding, because they replace some characters automatically for you. Use one of the great text editors especially made for coding out there, like [Atom](https://atom.io/), [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) or [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) to work with HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

---

**UPDATE**: Of course, three dots aren't correct either and won't work, I think. Try two dots to move up one directory and one dot to stay in the directory you are currently. In this case, removing the point and the slash is even shorter:

And finally, here is your fixed img element (Although, I don't know if the path is right.):

```html
<img src="./images/adam_photo.jpg" alt="dont_print_this_damnit" />
// OR:
<img src="images/adam_photo.jpg" alt="dont_print_this_damnit" />
```

For more info about these dot notations, check this nice article:

https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
<img src="images/adam_photo.jpg" alt="dont_print_this_damnit" />
```

Comment: This one did it. Why this one worked and the others didn't, I do not know. Upon looking closer, I think it is because the Mac TextEdit program was using strange quotation mark symbols, different from those that you used which I copied and pasted. Time to ditch this program. Thanks for your help!

Comment: in HTML the correct quotation is " " instead of  “  “ regardless what tool are using but definitely you can use Adobe Dreamweaver or any kind of text editor that support HTML syntax to help you to identify the problem and overcome any of these tedious syntax error

Answer (score 1):

That's because according to your relative path, the image is supposed to be located at `/Users/Adam/Documents/images/adam_photo.jpg`

Try changing the `../` to `./` to indicate the file location is at the same directory.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<img src="images/adam_photo.jpg" alt="dont_print_this_damnit" />
```

you have accidentally entered three periods "." in ".../images".

Two periods means go up one directory and one period means current directory

Comment: I still get "don't_print_this_damnit" after copying and pasting your solution.

Comment: perhaps the quotation mark is causing the error... sorry about that. Use " instead of  “

Answer (score 0):

Try do do this:

```
<img src=“your path/images/adam_photo.jpg” alt=“dont_print_this_damnit” />
```

or maybe this? no dots if that is your exact path then this will work:

```
    <img src=“/images/adam_photo.jpg” alt=“dont_print_this_damnit” />
```

Also try:

```
<img src=“./images/adam_photo.jpg” alt=“dont_print_this_damnit” />
```

Or:

```
    <img src=“images/adam_photo.jpg” alt=“dont_print_this_damnit” />
```

## edit:

You get this because you dont have on local disk, it will return alt because image is not found! your image in the correct place you cant get the image from a file. your code may really be working just not found immage!
do this!

```
 <img src="file:///Users/Adam/Documents/adam_webfolder/images/adam_photo.jpg
" alt="dont_print_this_damnit" />
```

it may have also been with your quotes!

Answer (score 0):

Is the image saved on your computer? If so, you only need this.

```
<img src=“../images/adam_photo.jpg” alt=“dont_print_this_damnit”/>
```

The ../ represents moving back a folder. Each / after that means going one step further, as /images means going into the images folder.

Comment: I still get "don't_print_this_damnit" after copying and pasting your solution.

Comment: yeah. I think that's probably because the file path was wrong. You said the the earlier answer was correct. That solution doesn't have '../'. This means going back a folder. Was your image outside of the images folder? If so, that's why.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<img src=“…//images//adam_photo.jpg” alt=“dont_print_this_damnit” />
```

Comment: I still get "don't_print_this_damnit" after copying and pasting your solution.